# BitLocker recovery key required after dual-booting Ubuntu

Tags: windows-10, boot, bitlocker

I have a Lenovo Thinkpad X1 Carbon with Windows 10 and a BitLocker-encrypted drive. I installed Ubuntu dual-boot recently and didn't realize I was supposed to disable BitLocker during the installation. Now every time I reboot Windows I have to enter a recovery key (which fortunately I was able to obtain from Microsoft's website). I tried disabling BitLocker and rebooting a few times afterward, then re-enabling it, but it still asks for a recovery key afterward. Any idea how to fix this?

The only option I know is to deactivate BitLocker completely. I don't particularly care about my drive being encrypted anyway, but I don't want to wait for it to decrypt for hours either...

Answer (score 0):

The optimal solution is to disable BitLocker completely, as you said. However, there is a way to keep Bitlocker on your computer and keep Ubuntu. I have not tried this on my own computer but it has worked well with others.

The way to do this is to uninstall Ubuntu. Remember to disable BitLocker from Windows. Provided that you have files you want to keep, I would suggest you take a backup (I would do this of the /home folder because that is where all your user files are (you would need to reinstall all user-installed programs and dependencies); otherwise you can just take a full backup and reinstall GRUB; more info about this is in [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/7809/how-to-back-up-my-entire-system).

The way to uninstall Ubuntu is easy. Boot from your LiveCD or create a USB with Rufus or some other utility and boot from that. After, open GParted and simply delete the partitions. However, you're not done. Because you deleted the partitions, you also deleted the grub files configuration files (everything in /boot/grub). As a result, if you boot up your computer now, you will get to a grub-rescue screen. So don't reboot just yet.

Open a terminal and run these commands to add a PPA and install boot-repair:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install boot-repair && boot-repair
```

After that, select "Recommended repair." This will create a new BCD for your Windows system and reinstall bootmgr to the MBR. It will ask you to create a pastebin after and give you a file telling you about what happened. After that, reboot. This should hopefully work. Otherwise, you can clone the drive to another one of the same size and format the whole drive, then move Windows back. Again, the best (and least risky) solution is to disable BitLocker completely.